# Python decimal.Decimal - getcontext().prec setting and number of decimals in output

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding, precision

I want to do arithmetic with converted number strings using decimal.Decimal. I want the return to have two decimals regardless of the quantity of decimals the converted number strings have.

In this particular case, why does two decimal precision give me one decimal return and why does three decimal precision give me the return I want (2 decimals -> 2.15)

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 2
a = Decimal(x.replace(',','.'))
b = Decimal(y.replace(',','.'))
print(a), print(b), print(a-b)
>>> 2.60 0.45 2.2

getcontext().prec = 3
a = Decimal(x.replace(',','.'))
b = Decimal(y.replace(',','.'))
print(a, b, a-b)
>>> 2.60 0.45 2.15
```

Comment: "precision" in this context (pun not intended) refers to the total number of significant digits, not the number of digits after the decimal point. Remember that the `Decimal` type is fundamentally a *floating-point* type, not a fixed-point type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `getcontext().prec` set the precision of digits which **Decimal** lib will use to return any calculated number, that is, prec = 2 will return 2 digits (first=2, second=2) and in prec = 3 that will show three numbers(first=2, second=1, third=5).

However , there is a trick here. When you created the a and b variables, the Decimal  used as precision the amount of digits from the number you gave to it. You can see that just calling the a or the b in your IDLE.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: @FlorinAndrei His ultimate question "Why does..." was answered. The implied question, "I want to have..." is accomplished using rounding and formatting.